# ExtJS Tab Panel Loader can't load the html page's javascript

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/ext-all.js?"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs-adv.js?"></script>
```

**tabs-adv.js**
create a tab panel then load the vehicle.html with loader

```
        ....

        var tabs = Ext.widget('tabpanel', {
        renderTo: 'tabs',
        id : 'tabspanel',
        cls : 'MainPanel',
        resizeTabs: true,
        enableTabScroll: true,
        width: window.innerwidth,
        height: window.innerHeight - 30, //30 because menu height is 30px
    tabBar: {
        layout: { pack: 'center' }
    },
        defaults: {
            autoScroll: false, //close the tab scrolling
            bodyPadding: 0 //must 0,not margin at all
        },
        items: [
        {
            closable: false,
            //html: '<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#cccccc;"><iframe src="vehicle/vehicle.html" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe></div>',
             loader: {
                autoLoad:true,
                url :'vehicle/vehicle.html'
            },
            iconCls: 'bus32',
            title: 'Vehicle Manage'
        }]
})
```

**vehicle.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Ext includes -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vehicle.js?<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
aa
<div id="toolbar"></div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately Loader didn't load the vehicle.js
loader only load the html content, but not included vehicle.html javascript.
any way to solve this problem?

p/s: i m facing this problem [EXT JS failed to load multi pages at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20588544/ext-js-failed-to-load-multi-pages-at-the-same-time) , both tabs are load at the same time with the ext-all.js will cause the application error, i have to try to use loader to prevent this happen,
I have tried, if the tabs are loaded with different ext-all.js will not be occured error, example first tab load ext-all.js, second tabs will load ext-all1.js 3th tab will load ext-all2.js.

### UPDATE

vehicle.js and driver.js also having the grid panel

**vehicle.js**

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel', {
    id:'mygridpanel',
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width:  window.innerWidth,
    header: false,
    height: window.innerHeight,
    store: UserStore,
    multiSelect: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: '_id',

                    text: 'Vehicle ID'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 126,
                    dataIndex: 'Plat_No',
                    text: 'Plat Number'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 200,
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    text: 'Added By'
                }
            ],listeners: {
                            itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

                                    if (record.get('_id') > 0){
                                        Ext.getCmp('BtnEdit').enable();
                                        Ext.getCmp('BtnDelete').enable();
                                    }else{
                                        Ext.getCmp('BtnEdit').disable();
                                        Ext.getCmp('BtnDelete').disable();
                                    };                                       
                            }},
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: '',
                            width: 65,
                            id : 'BtnAdd',
                            icon: '',
                            iconCls: 'add',
                            text: 'Add'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: '',
                            id : 'BtnEdit',
                            width: 65,
                            icon: '',
                            iconCls: 'edit',
                            disabled: true,
                            text: 'Edit'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: '',
                            id : 'BtnDelete',
                            width: 65,
                            icon: '',
                            iconCls: 'delete',
                            disabled: true,
                            text: 'Delete'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            cls: '',
                            id : 'BtnRefresh',
                            width: 65,
                            icon: '',
                            iconCls: 'refresh',
                            text: 'Refresh'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

}); 
var gridwin = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel');
```

Comment: Stick to my answer to the question you linked. You still talk about ext-all1 and 2. Change your mind and you will go further.

Comment: Ext will not execute JS that you inject into the page witha loader. You have to add the handler for your HTML yourself. A loader will only load clean HTML (it gets sanitized)

Comment: @Juan Mendes how to add a handle in vehicle.html ?

Comment: @Juan Mendes Please provide some example, i will mark as answer

Comment: Please read the documentation and get through the examples http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/application_architecture and http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/mvc_pt1.

Comment: You have to change your paradigm. ExtJs is about replacing html by javascript : Your html should have an empty body and just include your app.js. ExtJs is NOT about glueing together pieces of html code, like jQuery.

Comment: @Lorenz Meyer loader are not albe to load the javascipt just the html code, but u said : `Your html should have an empty body and just include your app.js.` how to include the app.js ? confusing

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Tab Panel are quite complicated, if like my code, vehicle.js and driver.js are included in the main html page. both gridpanel will show in a one main page.

Answer (score 1):

The loader is not supposed to load your javascript. With extjs, you should have only one javascript file. Use events to execute javascript code while rendering your panels, especially use the render event.

1. Put your vehicle.js in your main .js file and remove the last line. This one goes into the event listener.
2. Change your tab item using an event handler

   ```
   items: [{
       closable: false,
       loader: {
           autoLoad:true,
           url :'vehicle/vehicle.html'
       },
       iconCls: 'bus32',
       title: 'Vehicle Manage',
       listeners: {
           render: function(){gridwin = Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel')}
       }
   }]
   ```

General remark 1: Do your homework and read the documentation. Stick to the recommended way. Why are you trying to work in such a convoluted way ? It shows that you didn't take the time to read and apply the basics.

General remark 2: You should concatenate all your .js sources in the production environment. The best thing is to use `sencha cmd`. You have to create an empty app, an then copy all your project into that empty app.

Comment: Please Provide some example code? please provide more detail

Comment: i really dont understand how is it work, i have 2 tabs, one is for vehicle, another 1 is for driver, both page are using `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` , when i only have 1 javascipt, both page's gridpanel will load in a html body.i have updated my question, please recheck

Comment: please provide a correct way for me, i hope that with a complete code example. thank a lot!

Comment: @chinye show me the content of the HTML and the JS files

Comment: @JuanMendes Updated vehicle.js , pls review my code

Comment: @ChinYe I completed my answer.

Comment: Note that you can dynamically load classes with Ext JS if you don't want to load all the code for all the views up front http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/LoaderDemo/ However,

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to mix up ExtJS with static pages - rather suitable for print previews or alike.

A secondary DOM needs to be created within an iFrame, which will cause the JS on page to execute - because it circumvents the ExtJS Loader completely - and therefore scripts will be properly parsed.

Here's an example, proven to be working (reduced to the least required):

```
items : [{
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {tag: 'iframe', src: ''}
}],
listeners: {
    boxready: function(){
        this.items.items[0].el.dom.src='vehicle.html';
    }
}
```

The listener for boxready causes some delay in execution (which was required for what I did).

When reading other answers, I'd comment: *How about thinking out of the box, once?*

... which even literally applies in this particular case :)

One simply has to know the rules in order to break them - the other way around won't work.

Comment: @ChinYe http://developer.sencha.com/pathway/sencha-model-view-controller-mvc - this is how things basically work. Two times renderTo won't work for sure - only the topmost element should have this property (unless not attempting to overwrite any DOM node).